# ODBC-ODBC Bridge (64bit to 32bit) - Looking for an alternative to EasySoft's solution

Tags: database

Has anyone worked with Easysoft's ODBC to ODBC bridge.   I needed a solution to allow Access 365 (64-bit) to connect to a proprietary database(32-bit).
I was successfully using a ODBC data sources in 32-bit for years both we needed to switch everything to 64-bit for performance.  The software (using the 32bit DB) is not available in 64-bit so I needed something to overcome the architecture incompatibility(cannot connect a 64-bit base app to a 32-bit DB).

Easysoft provides a solution (their ODBC-ODBC Bridge) which we are currently trying and it works perfectly.  It's basically a ODBC driver that allows you to created a new DNS that you set in-between your 64-bit app and the 32-bit ODBC data sources.

ACCESS/VBA(64-bit) --> EASYSOFT ODBC(64-bit) --> OLD ODBC(32-bit) --> ERP database (32-bit)

The licence comes up to about 2500 USD.   I was looking for a more affordable solution for my client.

Any suggestions?

Thanks guys.